# Is there a way to add or remove a line of an LINQ to DB Query based on if the value being checked is null?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

If I have a query like this:

```
String Category = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Product"].ToString();

IQueryable<ItemFile> pressReleases = from file in connection.ItemFile
                                                           where file.Type_ID == 8
                                                                && file.Category == Category 
                                                           select file;
```

Is there a way to make this LINQ Query so that I do no use the line `file.Category == Category`  if Category is null or empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about don't add that `where` unless you need to?

```
IQueryable<ItemFile> pressReleases = from file in connection.ItemFile
                                     where file.Type_ID == 8
                                     select file;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Category)) {
    pressReleases = pressReleases.Where(file => file.Category == Category);
}
```

This works because LINQ queries are composable with deferred execution, so this filter is still part of the final TSQL.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you wanted but will render the same result:

```
String Category = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Product"].ToString();

IQueryable<ItemFile> pressReleases = from file in connection.ItemFile
                                     where file.Type_ID == 8
                                     && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Category) || file.Category == Category)
                                     select file;
```

Comment: Sani, I'm thinking that the OP is concerned where "Category" is null or empty, not file.Category.  If so, I think your solution would exclude some items that should be included.